# Mongo: one-to-many relationship & ObjectId or custom id?

Tags: mongodb, collections, relationship

In MongoDB I have a collection of users and a collection of books. A user can own a book and this gives the structure as follows:

```
   {
      username: 'myuser',
      ownedBooks: []
   }

   {
      title: 'my book',
      author: ''
   }
```

After reading documentation on '[one-to-many](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-referenced-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/)' relationships, I find myself wondering whether I should be using the Mongo ObjectId as reference or whether I should generate my own unique id for an item in my collection, independent of the Mongo ID (such as based on an [auto-increment](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) field)?

Comment: You can store the id, or even a reference. Don't see why you would want to generate your own unique id...

Comment: I was just looking at the example and it threw me. Still new and trying to get a feel of best practices. Thanks.